# Servlet multipart config can't upload larger files

Tags: java, servlets

I am using `@MultipartConfig` for uploading files into a database but it works only for small files, smaller than 5 MB. How to improve my code to work with larger files?

```
@WebServlet(name = "Upload", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        InputStream in = null;

        Part filePart = request.getPart("pdffile");

        if (filePart != null) {
            in = filePart.getInputStream();
        }
        Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("Connection");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO storepdf (pdffile) VALUES (?)";
        try (PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            if (in != null) {
                stat.setBlob(1, in);
            }
            int i = stat.executeUpdate();
            request.setAttribute("res", i);

        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("finish.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the server allows you to let the users upload more than this. For instance tomcat has configs to limit the upload size (`maxPostSize`in `server.xml`), and by default it's limited to 2MB.

Not just that, the read/write timeout also could close the connection if the upload gets long!(for example low-bandwidth)

You may print the exception you `catch` to find out if there was any issue you could get it in server.

*(p.s the way you SQL, is so scary, datasource pool?)*

Comment: I am using contextlistener to initialize my app with database connection and set connection object as an context attribute.